# Throwing dice: Compute the probability of strictly increasing values in the first $n$ throws

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, dice

Let a die be thrown $m$ times. What is the probability of strictly increasing values in the first $n< m$ throws? In other words, compute the probability $P(X=n)$ with $X\,\widehat{=}$"The first $n$ face values are strictly increasing".

---

The problem here is that I can't seem to find a rule which is common to how the probabilities of $P(X=1),P(X=2),\ldots$ seem to form in order to arrive at a general rule. How do I approach this?

Comment: Clarification:  (a)  is "strongly decreasing" the same thing as "strictly decreasing", i.e., each throw is strictly less than the previous throw?  (b) You mention both "strongly decreasing" and "strongly increasing" in the question;  was this intentional?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Sorry for the confusion, I meant "strictly increasing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set of all rolls of $n$ dice, each die having $N$ sides.  There are $N^n$ such sequences. How many of these sequences are strictly increasing?

Every possible sequence of $n$ strictly increasing die rolls can be obtained by selecting $n$ distinct values, without replacement, from the set of the die's $N$ faces, and then sorting them into a strictly increasing order.  There are $N \choose n$ distinct ways to do this.

Thus, the probability of a sequence of $n$ rolls being strictly increasing is
$$
p = \frac{1}{N^n} { N \choose n}.
$$

For $N = 6$, these values work out to be:

- $n = 1$:  $p = 1$
- $n = 2$:  $p = 5/12$
- $n = 3$:  $p = 5/54$
- $n = 4$:  $p = 5/432$
- $n = 5$:  $p = 1/1296$
- $n = 6$:  $p = 1/46656$